# Implement prefetch with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing, prefetch

I want to implement prefetch functionality for a customized class using multiprocessing of `python`.

Suppose we have the following class `Sequence` which can get batch of data by using index with `__getitem__` method

```py
class Sequence:
    
    def __init__(self):
        """ class initialization """

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """ get data by index, this step may cost some time """
```

and a very time-comsuming function `run_experiment` to process the data returned by `Sequence`.

Typically I will use `for-loop` as follows

```py
for i in range(1000):
    data = Sequence[i]
    output = run_experiment(data)
```

However, since `run_experiment` is time-consuming, I would expect that `Sequence` can pre-preparing some data for future uses while `run_experiment` is still running. Naive idea will be using `queue` to collect  data returned by `Sequence` in advance and directly get data from `queue` to feed `run_experiment`. However, I have no idea how to implement such functionality in `Sequence` while not changing too much of its API. All I need is a simple demo of solution for my problem.